# How to replace property without effecting data in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have data in format like this:-

```
a.arr= [
0:{
name: abc,
dob: 18/12/1917,
panNo: ASDFG6789K
},
1:{
name: xyz,
dob: 1/2/1917,
panNo: WERTY6789K
}
]
```

I want to remove 0 and 1 and convert it in like this:-

```
a.arr= [
{
name: abc,
dob: 18/12/2017,
panNo: ASDFG6789K
},
{
name: xyz,
dob: 1/2/1917,
panNo: WERTY6789K
}
]
```

If I use delete then it removes the data as well inside object. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: the first structure is not valid.

Comment: Try to use arr.reverse();

Comment: The first structure is an output from a `console.log`, the `0` and `1` aren't there actually they simply symbolize the array index.

Comment: How are you currently removing those?  The first structure doesn't look valid to me, so how are you interacting with it at all?

Answer (score 0):

As some of the previous commenters said, your first code snippet does not contain valid JavaScript. However, if both the `0` and `1` become strings, as well as all of the values (`abc`, `18/12/1917`, etc.), your data would look like this:

```
var a = {};
a.arr = [
  {
    "0": {
      name: "abc",
      dob: "18/12/1917",
      panNo: "ASDFG6789K"
    }
  },
  {
    "1": {
      name: "xyz",
      dob: "1/2/1917",
      panNo: "WERTY6789K"
    }
  }
];
```

To remove the `0` and `1`, you could then do this:

```
var arr = a.arr.map(function(d){
  var key = Object.keys(d)[0];
  return d[key];
});

a.arr = arr;

// a.arr is now:
[{
    "name": "abc",
    "dob": "18/12/1917",
    "panNo": "ASDFG6789K"
}, {
    "name": "xyz",
    "dob": "1/2/1917",
    "panNo": "WERTY6789K"
}]
```